# ERROR: CANT_REREAD: The directory named as part of the path /home/app/logs/celery.log does not exist

Tags: python, django, celery, ubuntu-16.04

I'm following a [tutorial on how to use Celery on my Django production server](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html#managing-the-worker-process-in-production-with-supervisord).

When I get to the bit where it says:

```
Now reread the configuration and add the new process:

    sudo supervisorctl reread
    sudo supervisorctl update
```

When I perform `sudo supervisorctl reread` in my server (Ubuntu 16.04) terminal, it returns this:

```
ERROR: CANT_REREAD: 
The directory named as part of the path /home/app/logs/celery.log does not exist. 
in section 'app-celery' (file: '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/app-celery.conf')
```

I've done all of the instructions prior to this including installing `supervisor` as well as creating a file named mysite-celery.conf (`app-celery.conf`) in the folder: /etc/supervisor/conf.d

If you're curious my app-celery.conf file looks like this:

```
[program:app-celery]
command=/home/app/bin/celery worker -A draft1 --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/app/draft1
user=zorgan
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/app/logs/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/app/logs/celery.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

stopasgroup=true

; Set Celery priority higher than default (999)
; so, if rabbitmq is supervised, it will start first.
priority=1000
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Have you made sure that the directory `/home/app/logs/` exists?

Comment: Yeah that was it - I changed it to `stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery.log` and `stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery.log` - however in the `supervisor` directory the file is called `supervisord.log` not `celery.log` - so do you know why the above still works?

Answer (score 6):

Somehow supervisor is not able to create the folder - /home/app/logs/.
You can create it manually using mkdir and restart the supervisor service

```
mkdir /home/app/logs
sudo service supervisor restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I added my username to the superisord.conf file under the [unix_http_server] section like so:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0770                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)
chown=appuser:supervisor        ;(username:group)
```

This seemed to work- time will tell if it continues working after I manage solve the rest of the supervisor issues.